# Does Razz Berry work for the next throw or catch?

Tags: pokemon-go

When using a Razz Berry to improve the chance a Pokemon won't break free — does it apply for your next *throw* or your next *catch* i.e. it doesn't matter how many Pokeballs it takes?

[image]

The exact wording says throw, but I've always felt like using a Razz Berry helps contain a Pokemon who's broken out a couple of times even if it takes two or three throws after using the Razz Berry (confirmation bias?). There's also the chance the item description doesn't match what's happening in the game.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I don't have evidence for this, per se, but I believe that it applies only to your next successful throw -- i.e., your next throw that actually hits the Pokemon.

I suspect this because you're unable to use a second Razz Berry immediately after using the first, or if you miss the Pokemon a bunch, but as soon as you make contact and it breaks free, you can use another Razz Berry.

---

To clarify:

On a **failed throw**, you throw a Pokeball but completely miss the Pokemon. **This does not use up a Razz Berry**.

On a **successful throw**, you throw a Pokeball and hit the Pokemon. It wiggles around a bit, and you either catch it or it breaks free. **This uses up the Razz Berry**, *whether you catch the Pokemon or not*.

If you want to boost your chances, then every time you hit the Pokemon with a throw, you'll need to use another Razz Berry.

Comment: So your next catch. It is a catch. Like, I caught the baseball but then it fell from my mitt. I still caught it. So it applies to your next catch, not throw. The answerer below you disagrees, so you have any sources?

Comment: @Insane No, it's your next throw. If you Razz Berry, then throw a Pokeball but miss, the Pokemon will still be there. Your future throws will not be affected by the Razz Berry. Unfortunately I don't have any direct source for you, but you should be able to verify on your app that you cannot use another Razz Berry if you completely miss the Pokemon, but you can if you hit it and it breaks free.

Comment: To me catching is getting the Pokemon in the ball — breaking free or not is a separate thing. A throw can fail or be successful.. either way what you're saying is still opposite to the other answer (not that I don't believe you).

Comment: You're working under the assumption that because you can't use another, the first is still in effect.  It would be strange if that wasn't the case, but it is what the tooltip on the item implies, and there's no concrete evidence either way.

Comment: @ThunderGuppy But if you use a Berry then hit the pokemon and he still breaks free, then you do need to use another one. So logic dicates that when you can't use another 1 it is still active.

Comment: @Lyrion, true, but the tooltip says next throw, so either that's a typo, or the logic is wonky, but I don't think we have the means of confirming which is true.  :/

Comment: @ThunderGuppy we do. When you use a Razz Berry it lowers the catch difficulty, this will in some cases cause the Pokemon to drop a difficulty category so much that there is a visible color difference in the colored circle during a throw. If that color doesn't change back after a missed throw, the theory is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I've read on this, and if your next throw catches the pokemon, the Razz Berry takes effect.

This doesn't mean you can just fail to throw on your next throw. The Razz Berry only works for that throw only. This means you HAVE to keep using Razz Berries no matter how many throws it takes if you really want to catch that pokemon.

Comment: Do you have a source to where you read about it, because the answer above you is the opposite.

Comment: This is wrong, if you miss your throw completely the Razz berry is still in effect. Because I once used it on a pokemon, then completely missed the throw. I figured I needed to use another Razz berry but it wouldn't let me because it was still active.

Comment: @Lyrion "it wouldn't let me" doesn't necessarily imply "because it was still active".

Comment: @Rawling Actually that's exactly what it implies. If you want to contest it you should back it up (not just you but the answerer, whoever).

Comment: @Insane "Implies" in a colloquial sense, maybe, but not in a logical one. The game could be coded to stop you using another berry until you get a hit, but without giving you any further benefit. Saying "it wouldn't let me" doesn't prove "it's still active".

Comment: @Rawling (I know this is like half a year later) The game _could_ be coded like that.  It is all speculation; that said, there is an _implication_ that the berry has not been used, because you cannot use another one.  It doesn't seem logical that you would be unable to use one even though the old one expired (especially given the circumstances of being able to use it again after a successful throw), therefore it is _implied_ (but not confirmed) that it is still active.  Implication is different than confirming evidence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of its former mechanics because I did not observe it before but after the Gen2 update with the introduction of the Pinap and Nanab berries they have also introduced a "Berry Status" feature into the game which displays both which berry has been used on the target Pokemon and also its availability. It's a little icon which appears to the upper right corner of the target Pokemon.

My observation is that berries don't always continue to be effective for the succeeding throws. Sometimes they even disappear after the first throw. This is especially annoying when using the Pinap berry for stage 2 and stage 3 Pokemon to grab the additional candy bonuses where your Pinap berry becomes obsolete after the first throw. I'm not used to observe that icon which causes me to miss its disappearance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how much this effects what anyone thinks about this issue but it occurs to me that when you throw a razzberry the Pokemon reacts with hearts and what not appearing around it and that only works until after you've thrown a ball so I have been working under the assumption that it only worked for the very next throw after the razzberry regardless of whether or not it was a good throw or a bad throw whether or not it cut the Pokemon or not.

Comment: Next time you miss, why don't you check if you can throw another berry (hint: you can't). This strongly indicates that the berry is still "good" until you actually hit the Pokemon with a ball.